# EF5 CodeFirst schema name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm developing this application where I have to read data from several tables (all with the same struture) in multiple schema (defined at run-time).
Using entity framework 5 with code first approach, I need a way to change the schema name of the entity.
At the moment I´m creating my DbContext using a constructor with two parameters, a DbConnection and the schema name (witch I use in the overridden OnModelCreating).

The first time I create the DbContext everything works fine and I´m able to get the data. But when I create a new DbContext with a second schema name,the DbConnection used by the DbContext is the one passed in the construtor but the schema name in the entity remains to be the first one since OnModelCreating is not called even though I´m creating a new instance of DbContext.

Any ideias?
Thanks

Edit: Don´t think it matters but I´m using a Oracle Database.

Comment: Why not create 2 seperate DBContexts or put both schemas in the same file?

Comment: The schemas to connect to are defined in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by creating a SQL Server user per schema (with the default schema set) and multiple connection strings.

In your application, create a connection string per user (schema).  Add a dbcontext constructor that accepts a connection string then pass in the appropriate connection string to the constructor.

Comment: That is actually what I have :) the problem is that I have to provide a schema name in the mapping of the entity or else EF while assume dbo. as schema.

Comment: oopps sorry.  Misread the question. See what you mean now.  Don't know the answer off top of my head.

Comment: Have you seen this - http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first/ - I only scanned it but it seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something by providing a custom database initializer (IDatabaseInitializer and Database.SetInitializer(new YouCustomInitializer());)

Comment: As far as I could understand the IDatabaseInitializer is used to create the Database, right? I´m working with existing databases

Comment: I believe the IDatabaseInitializer is called every time your context is initialized. You could perhaps do some work at this point to recreate the different schemas?